# How to select value in object with key in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to know how to select value with key in d3.js

I've imported data from csv. 
The result is as follows.

[image: This shows objects]

That screen is the result of this code.

```
data = data.sort(function(a, b){
    console.log(a);
    return d3.descending(a.Year, b.Year);
});
```

I can select amount or year with `a.Amount` or `a.Year`
But how can I select `Grant Organization`?
`a.Grant Organization` is not working.

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `a["Grant Organization"]` instead, it should work

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors for more information

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`Bracket-notation`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)

> *An object property name can be any `valid JavaScript string`, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, **a property name that has a space** or a hyphen, or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square bracket notation.*

```js
data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.descending(a['Grant Organization'], b['Grant Organization']);
});
```